# Related to Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-6

I am working on microsoft visual studio 6.0

There are 2 dsp files namely, 
1). A.dsp 
2). B.dsp

I set A.dsp as my ACTIVE PROJECT and chosen configuration as "Debug_mode2" [there r two debug modes available: Debug_mode1, Debug_mode2 under configuration]...and B.dsp is dependent[Similarly to A.dsp, My B.dsp is also having 2 Debug modes: Debug_mode1, Debug_mode2 under configuration].

Now, The problem is...When I am trying to rebuild A.dsp file, it is selecting "Debug_mode1" of B.dsp and trying to build B.dsp as well....BUT I want that Debug_mode2 of B.dsp should be selected and then build B.dsp.

Thanks.

I dont know how to change this default behaviour.

Comment: Visual Studio 6 is dead. It’s unlikely that you will be able to get help with it anywhere.

Comment: No one is answering my query :'( !!!!

Comment: Well have a bit of patience, you haven’t even waited for 15 minutes. But like I said, you’ll likely not get an answer at all – you should really upgrade to a recent version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Because there's no one here that would bother to use a compiler that was old when Win2k came out. There are 5(!) newer versions of that compiler/IDE, all of them having less bugs and more features than VS6. Why don't you use one of those? You wouldn't use one of those ugly huge mobile phones with long antennae if you could have a smart phone for free, would you?

Comment: Actually...I cant upgrade to any newer version :( I have to do it on this older version only.

Comment: @ArneMertz, don't be snobbish. Most probably he is not the one who decides what IDE to use. Becides VS6 is perfectly stable and very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. And not only in VS6, recent versions of VS handle the configurations just the same way AFAIK.

What you can do however is rename your `Debug_mode2` config of `B.dsp`  to `Debug_mode1`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to rename this?  I am new to Visual Studio.

Comment: @user1367292, I think you just go to `Build`->`Confugurations` and do it from there. If there is no "Rename" button, then just clone your config with different name and then remove the old one